# wordpress Error establishing a database connection, the page can not display

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to Wordpress. I uploaded data to cpanel, but when I tried to borrows the link to display the website I get this message when I look at the error log.

> Error establishing a database connection

There were the below two error messages. I hope somebody can help me.

> PHP Warning: require(/home/.../public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/.../public_html/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/.../public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19

Comment: this error occurs due to invalid database connection

Comment: Possibly also a file permissions problem. Tha'ts the first suggestion that comes up when you google the messages.  It would get a DB connection it couldn't open the wp-config file.  It is weird that it gives an error in public_html/wp-settings.php after reporting that it couldn't find it.    Follow this https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress step by step.  Google the messages when you get a problem.  One can usually find a similar thing reported and solution presented.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a bad (incomplete) file upload.
Try to upload again your Wordpress installation.